# Capture quantified character set or a single char

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm not sure if the title is accurate, so I'm sorry if this is a duplicate.

From my understanding, `(a|b)` matches either `a` or `b`. This can be extended, like `([\w]|@)` to match either a word character or `@`.

My question is: Why does this not work with a quantifier? I am trying to match a quantified character set or a single `@`, but `([\w\.\-]*|@)` won't match `@`.

Could anyone explain the cause of this behavior and maybe the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` means "match zero or more".  Thus, the first part of your pattern can successfully match nothing (an empty string).  The first part is always successful, so it never tries the second part.

You have two options to solve this:

1. Use `+` to require at least one character: `([\w\.\-]+|@)`
2. Put the `@` first: `(@|[\w\.\-]*)`.  This is useful if you still want an empty string to match, but you want to match `@` if it is there.

**Update:** Linuxios suggests that Ruby won't allow `*` within a subpattern.  I'm not a Ruby user, but if that is true, you could get the equivalent of option 2 like this:

```
(@|[\w\.\-]+)?
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby doesn't allow variable quantifiers in an or that can match *nothing*, because nothing always matches, making the or pointless.

Comment: Thanks. No, I'm trying to match lines from a DNS zonefile.

Comment: @dan1111: Variable quantifiers that can match 0 or more. + is *1* or more. However * and ? are 0 or (more/1)

Comment: @pduersteler" Fixed. Sorry. It just looked that way, and I had to point you at the real regex if you *we're* trying to match email.